# Group_Concat columna que devuelve varios valores

Tags: mysql

Lo planteo diferente....
Tengo los siguientes datos y deseo el resultado mostrado al final.. lo intente de varias meneras pero no me funciono adecuadamente.

tabla articulos
tabla tipocodigo
tabla articulotipocodigo
tabla listaprecio
tabla articulolistaprecio

tabla codigos: CodigoBarra, codigofabrica
tabla listaprecio: preciomayorista, precio minorista

1 articulo puede tener 0, 1 ó n registros e

TABLAS BASE
tabla articulo

```
+---------+----------------+
| IdArt   | NombreArt      |
+---------+----------------+
|    1    | HARINA         |
|    2    | ARROZ          |
|    3    | FIDEO          |
+--------------------------+
```

taba tipocodigo

```
+------------------------+
| IdCod | NombreCodigo   |
+------------+-----------+
|   1   | CODIGO BARRA   |
|   2   | CODIGO FABRICA |
+------------------------+
```

tabla listaprecio

```
+----------------------------+
| IdLista | NombreLista      |
+----------------------------+
|    1    | PRECIO MAYORISTA |
|    2    | PRECIO MINORISTA |
+----------------------------+
```

tabla articulotipocodigo (relaciona un registro de tabla artículo con un registro de tabla tipocodigo)
puede haber 0,1,2 registros asociados o sea 1 producto puede no tener codigo  por ej el articulo 3 no tiene ningun tipo de codigo asociado en este ejempl el articulo idart=1 tiene 2 codigos, el idart=2 1 codgio y el idart no tiene ninguno

```
+------------------------+
|IdArt|IdLista | codigo  |
+------------+-----------+
|  1  |   1    |  000111 |
|  1  |   2    |  aaabbb |
|  2  |   1    |  222333 |
+------------------------+
```

tabla articulolistaprecio (relaciona un registro de tabla artículo con un registro de tabla listaprecio) puede haber 0,1,2 registros asociados o sea un articulo puede tener ningun precio, precio mayorista o precio minorista o ambos..

```
+--------------+---------+
|IdArt|IdLista |  precio |
+------------+-+---------+
|  1  |   1    |   2.30  |
|  1  |   2    |   3.40  |
|  2  |   1    |   5.60  |
+--------------+---------+
```

El Resultado Esperado es

```
+----------------------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------+
|IdArt|Articulo|PrecioMinorista|PrecioMayorista|CodigoDeBarra|CodigoDeFabrica|
+------------------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
|  1  | HARINA |   2.30        +      3.40     +   000111    +   aaabbb      |
|  2  | ARROZ  |   5.60        +               +   222333    +               |
|  3  | FIDEO  |   3.40        +               +             +               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Por favor coloca un par de registros de ejemplo de las tablas de las cuales extraes la información, para entender porque se muestran de esa forma

Comment: Hola. Gracias por responder. Me estoy demorando en subir ejemplos porque estoy tratando de filtrar.. tengo como 100 mil registros... pero ya subo.. voy a editar mi pregunta.. asi como lo sugiere stackoverflow

Comment: Recuerda aportar el resultado que esperas para esos datos de prueba

Comment: El problema en el resultado es unicamente en el atributo Precio
"Precio1" 
"256.00000,256.00000"
donde como se ve aparece 2 veces el mismo valor... y deberia aparecer solo una vez.
"256.00000"

Como comentario, con otro conjutno de datos mas grande se repiten mas veces el mismo valor como resultado en el atributo precio.. algo como 
"256.00000 256.00000 256.00000 256.00000"

Comment: Es mejor que modifiques la pregunta añadiendo esa aclaración y los datos de partida en SQL (con `INSERT`) para que podamos llegar a ese resultado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te envío una de las posibles querys con las que puedes obtener lo que estás buscando:

```
SELECT * FROM articulo LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT IdArt,precio PrecioMinorista
      FROM articulolistaprecio
      WHERE idlista=1
  ) c1 USING(IdArt)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT IdArt,precio PrecioMayorista
      FROM articulolistaprecio
      WHERE idlista=2  
  ) c2 USING(IdArt)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT IdArt,codigo CodigoDeBarra
      FROM articulotipocodigo
      WHERE idlista=1
  ) c3 USING(IdArt)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT IdArt,codigo CodigoDeFabrica
      FROM articulotipocodigo
      WHERE idlista=2
  ) c4 USING(IdArt);
```

Así como el dataset para las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE articulo(
  IdArt int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  NombreArt varchar(15)
  );
INSERT INTO articulo (NombreArt) VALUES
  ('HARINA'),('ARROZ'),('FIDEO');
CREATE TABLE tipocodigo(
  IdCod int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  NombreCodigo varchar(15)
  );
INSERT INTO tipocodigo (NombreCodigo) VALUES
  ('CODIGO BARRA'),('CODIGO FABRICA');
CREATE TABLE listaprecio(
  IdLista int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  NombreLista varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO listaprecio (NombreLista) VALUES 
  ('PRECIO MAYORISTA'),('PRECIO MINORISTA');
CREATE TABLE articulotipocodigo(
  IdArt int,
  IdLista int,
  codigo varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO articulotipocodigo (IdArt, IdLista, codigo) VALUES
   (1,1,'000111'),(1,2,'aaabbb'),(2,1,'222333');
CREATE TABLE articulolistaprecio(
  IdArt int,
  IdLista int,
  precio float
  );
INSERT INTO articulolistaprecio (IdArt, IdLista, precio) VALUES 
  (1,1,2.30),(1,2,3.40),(2,1,5.60);
```

Y el resultado:

> ```
> IdArt NombreArt PrecioMin PrecioMay Barras Fabrica
>     1 HARINA          2,3       3,4 000111 aaabbb
>     2 ARROZ           5,6    (null) 222333 (null)
>     3 FIDEO        (null)    (null) (null) (null)
> ```

Fíjate que difiere de lo que esperas porque, en tus datos de muestra, no figura el precio del FIDEO.

Como desconozco cuánto sabes de MySQL porque no has aportado tus intentos, no sabría qué explicarte de esta consulta. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios y ampliaré la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, tienes razon... fideo no tiene ningún precio.  Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de revisar.
Apenas pueda lo pruebo y te digo como me va.

Comment: Sabes que me costo un poco readaptarla, ya que por ej. los campos clave como idart en realidad son compuestos, pero me quedó funcionando. Mil gracias Mil. 
Como comentario lo tenia resuelto de otra forma, pero tu solución es muy eficiente en cuanto a tiempo que es lo que me estaba matando.

Comment: Genial, entonces, ya que has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)